# Attribiute Validation in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to validate the fields entered by the user in the form. I tried this but it isn't validating fields at all.Even if i enter no record it does not gives error message. Is there anything else i need to add like script or libraries ?
which library is to add ?

View Model(Class):

```
    public class RegisterationLoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string pass { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Mobile_Number1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_On { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Provience { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Home_Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string User_Role { get; set; }
    public int Approved { get; set; }

}
```

Below is the View:

```
    <form action="@Url.Action("Index","SignUp")" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

Full Name @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Full_Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Full_Name)
<br />
Email @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
<br />
Password  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pass, new { @class = "form-control", type = "password" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pass)
<br />
Date of Birth @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date_of_Birth, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Date_of_Birth)
<br />
Address @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Home_Address, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Home_Address)
<br />
Mobile Number-1 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Mobile_Number1, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Mobile_Number1)
<br />
CNIC @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CNIC, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Full_Name)
<br />
Country @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Country, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Country)
<br />
Provience @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Provience, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Provience)
<br />
City @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.City)
<br />

@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Student",
        Value = "Student"
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Trainer",
        Value = "Trainer",
        Selected = true
    });

}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User_Role, listItems, "-- Select Role --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.User_Role)
<br />
<br />
@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Male",
        Value = "Male"
    });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Female",
        Value = "Female",
        Selected = true
    });

}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, listItems2, "-- Select Gender --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Gender)
<br />
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Sign Up </button>
```

Comment: How does your httppost action method looks like ?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(RegisterationLoginViewModel svm)
        {
            if (svm == null)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Null_SignUp_View");
            }

            string RegisterStudent_Response = db.Register(svm);
            if(RegisterStudent_Response=="1")
            {
                RedirectToAction("ThankYou_View");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("ThankYou_View");
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your current code in your HttpPost action is always return a RedirectResult using the `RedirectToAction` method. If you want to see the validation errors generated by the model validation framework when you submit the form, you need to return to the same view.

Also you may use the `ModelState.IsValid` property to check whether the submitted form data passed the validations. If it did, you can continue to execute your code like saving to db and redirecting.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(RegisterationLoginViewModel svm)
{ 
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     //save
     var result = db.Register(svm);
     return RedirectToAction("ThankYou_View");
   }
   //Model validation failed. Let's return to same view.
   // to do : Make sure to reload any stuff you need in view (Ex: ViewBag etc)
   return View(svm);
}
```